# Angular Jasmine, What is the difference between angular.mock.inject and inject?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

When describing a unit test we do the following:

```
describe('Some definition', function () {
    // ... unit tests 
}
```

Before each test we may want to inject dependencies for all specs, however there are two ways to do this. **What is the difference between using `angular.mock.inject()` and just `inject()` in a beforeEach()?**

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
    someService = $injector.get('someService');
}));
```

and

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    someService = $injector.get('someService');
}));
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inject()` is just a shortcut to `angular.mock.inject()`.

Comment: "NOTE: This function is also published on window for easy access." on the Angular docs. The wording of this threw me off a bit. I didn't spot it. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Saving the next me a click: [Location of "_NOTE: This function is also published on window for easy access._"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject)